# When installing the Parse SDK in my react native project then it shows Can't find variable: localStorage error

Tags: javascript, react-native, parse-platform, parse-javascript-sdk

When I install parse library in my existing project in react-native then it shows can't find variable: localStorage Error and break my app.

When I used install.save method then it shows the error.

```
let install = new Parse.Installation();
        install.set("deviceType", navigator.userAgent);
        install.save().then((resp) => {
        console.log('Created install object', resp); })
         this.setState({
          result: 'New object created with objectId: ' + resp.id
         })
        },err => {
        console.log('Error creating install object', err);
        this.setState({
          result: 'Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + err.message
        })
      })
```

Comment: did you tried `window.localStorage ?

Comment: window.localStorage means @AkhilAravind

Comment: Have you imported the react native version of parse? `const Parse = require('parse/react-native');` - Have you set up async storage? https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-JS#using-parse-on-different-platforms

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse can't find localStorage variable in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32544406/parse-cant-find-localstorage-variable-in-react-native)

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution for this it's Parse library issue and I upgrade the library and issue solved.